# How to redirect output of one module only to a file?

Tags: logging, stdout, python-2.x, io-redirection

I am making a server with Python 2. For that I use the module CGIHTTPServer and I want to redirect only the outputs of that module to a file. I tried already `CGIHTTPServer.sys.stdout = open("file.log", "w")`, `CGIHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPServer.sys,stdout = open("file.log", "w")`, but both had simply no effect. Is that possible at all, and if yes, how ?

Comment: Do you want to redirect stdout to a file?

Comment: @tansy Yes, but only these parts that come from a specific module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a module you want to redirect everything to stdout.

```py
import sys

stdout_sav = sys.stdout
fout = open('file.log', 'w')
sys.stdout = fout

# since now, whatever is printed to standard output goes to file

(...)


# at the end restore standard output

sys.stdout = stdout_sav
fout.close()
```

Comment: Yeah, but what if the module is builtin in Python and I cannot modify it (at least not without admin rights), and don't ___want___ to modify it, because then, the output would always go to that file. If I would make one program where I want the output from that module go to file, and another where I want all output to be printed, your solution won't work. Another problem is that, if I share my program with others, _they_ will not have the modified module, and I really cannot expect from my end users to mess around with admin files !

Comment: Unless there is some namespace voodoo to achieve that, I don't know how to do such a trick.

Comment: You can try to make a class that redirects stdout and if only this class uses *CGIHTTPServer* then only its messages will go to log file.

Comment: Umm, can you make a little example ? I somehow don't really understand your explanations ...

Comment: [Here](https://izziswift.com/how-to-redirect-stdout-to-both-file-and-console-with-scripting/) you have examples of "tee" equivalent ([tee.1](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tee), [tee.2](https://linux.die.net/man/2/tee)) in python. They all utilise classes. This may help you. If you use cgi module within class that redirects stdout to log file then it can work.